# Поиск слова в строке и замена его на слово большей длины

Tags: c

Есть строка "my destiny", ее нужно заменить, к примеру, на "your destiny". Через функцию strstr найдем слово my. Пытался использовать strncpy, но функция преобразовывала строку в yourestiny, что вполне логично.

Как можно заменить my на слово большей длины (к примеру, your)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала сдвигаем вручную предыдущую строку на разницу в количестве символов, потом записываем нужное слово в строку. Ничего стандартного я не припомню.

---

Второй способ:
    #include < iostream >

```
void Replace(char str[],char a[],char b[],char buffer[])
{
    int i,j,pos=0;
    for(i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
        for(j=0;str[i+j]&&a[j];j++)   //начинается ли с i-ой позиции строка a
            if(str[i+j]!=a[j]) break;
        if(!a[j])  //если a[j]=0, то мы дошли до конца строки a
        {
            i+=j-1;  //в j у нас длина стоки a, которую мы перепрыгиваем
            for(j=0;b[j];j++) buffer[pos++]=b[j];  //на место стоки a ставим строку b
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[pos++]=str[i];   //просто копируем символ
        }
        buffer[pos]=NULL;  //ставим конец строки
    }
    strcpy(str,buffer);  //копируем в первоначальную строку
}

int main()
{
    char str[100]="my destiny, not my destiny,mydestiny";
    char a[]="my",b[]="your";
    char buffer[200];
    Replace(str,a,b,buffer);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо. Это именно то, что мне было необходимо!

Answer (score 3):

Если на основе strstr и strcpy, то нужно создать буфер куда будет копироваться результат.

- Создаем новую строку.
- Ищем первое вхождение подстроки для замены.
- Копируем в новую строку старую строку до вхождения.
- Копируем в новую строку текст замены.
- Повторяем для всех других вхождений.

Comment: а можно пример такого кода?