# Дополнение готовой функции

Tags: c, строки, функции

[Поиск слова в строке и замена его на слово большей длины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/60089/363966) 
Хочу задать вопрос по этой функции, она работает прекрасно, но хотелось бы узнать каким образом можно сделать проверку на разделители, чтобы в строке заменялось ТОЛЬКО полноценное слово, а не его часть в составе слова (те, mydestiny НЕ заменялось на yourdestiny).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, надо просто проверить, что найденное `my` не является частью слова, т.е. что перед ним не буква (или что `m` - первый символ строки), и что за ним тоже идет не буква (или что `y` - последний символ строки).

Надо просто четко определиться, что же такое *слово*.

Comment: Я это понимаю, но не могу понять в какую часть функции можно вставить эту проверку и как написать эту проверку

Comment: В тот момент, когда вы обнаружили `my` и перед тем, как выполняете замену.